# Strange errors from Microsoft Access database used in Web API

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, asp.net-web-api

I work on a product that was built a long time ago using Microsoft Access for the database. It was mainly a desktop MS Access application, but was moved to the web some time ago. As the popularity of our product has grown and with an increasing amount of integrations with other systems, we built a Web API.

This has worked fine for a couple of years, but recently we've experienced some strange errors that prevents users from accessing the API on one specific server.

Due to the fact that we use MS Access we have our API duplicated across 4-5 servers. Now, only users of the API on one of these servers are experiencing this error. This is also by far the server which has the most API usage, which makes me fear that we have reached some kind of limit with MS Access.

This is what the error looks like when attempting to make a request to the API (which contacts the Access DB):

[Error](http://pastebin.com/7kru8PWv)

Has anybody experienced this error before? If I recycle the application pool in IIS, the error goes away but will reappear after about 30 minutes. While I could make IIS recycle the application pool like every 10 minutes, I doubt that would be a good long-term solution.

Any suggestions? Is there another way to fix this or do we have to switch to a more suitable DBMS, like SQL Server?

Comment: It sounds like you should migrate away from Access as your database back-end, for reasons explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I would be really grateful if someone who has experienced a similar problem could elaborate on what this specific error means (or could potentially mean).